# Use method of base class from derived object

Tags: inheritance

I have a confuse when derived object choose suitable method from this code:

```
class Shape {
public:
virtual void draw()
{
    cout << "Shape::draw\n"; 
}
void erase()
{
    cout << "Shape::erase \n";
}
void redraw(){
    erase(); draw();
}
};         
class Circle:public Shape{
public:
virtual void draw()
{
    cout << "Circle::draw\n";
}
void erase(){
    cout << "Circle::erase\n";
}
};

void main(){
Circle c;
Shape s1 = c;
Shape& s2 = c;
Shape* s3 = &c;
c.redraw();
s1.redraw();
s2.redraw();
s3.redraw();
}
```

When I compile it, c use erase of Shape. I do not know why? C has its own erase method why it has use of Shape?

Comment: erase is not `virtual`. I guess that breaks dynamic dispatch.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I knew it. But my question is how machine (computer) choose this function